# Record moves on Android

Tags: android, video

I am trying to find out how to record moves made by one person and then make a sort of movie out of it, which can be sent to another person. Just like it is in Draw Something.

I have had a few ideas that do not deal with recording the screen but rather the moves made. But if i could Actually record video that would be a big time saver.

Any idea how Draw Something accomplishes this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Draw Something but if I understood your question then it shouldn't be too hard:

- You react on the onTouch() method in order to know when TouchDown/TouchMove/TouchUp Events occur. On touchDown you start drawing, for each move you add another line and stop when touchUp occurs.
- Basically, if you want to repeat that procedure later on (or on another device) all you have to do is store each touch event(i.e. touchType(up,down,move), position(x,y)) and a timestamp to know when the event occured.
- Finally, you can animate the drawing using a timer and the timestamps.